# When locking screen on OS X Chrome cancels downloads

Tags: macos, google-chrome, screen-lock

When I lock my screen using <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>eject</kbd> while Chrome is downloading, the download is canceled. I get back to my computer and see that download is not active. I also noticed that video streams I'm watching (such as live TV) also stop.

My question is, can I change this behaviour? When the download is big I cannot lock my computer for long time and I feel my computer is compromised when I leave it.

Is it OS X issue or Chrome?

I have MacBook Pro (13 inch, mid 2012) with El Capitan.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Sorry for the bad phrasing.. :-(. I edited the question, hopefully it is clearer now. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>eject</kbd>, use the **Login Window** instead as this does not interrupt your download or streaming.

To use **Login Window**, go to:

*System Preferences -> Users > Login Options > Show fast user switching menu as 'Icon'*

You will see a "user icon" top right bar left of Spotlight icon. Click on this then click on **Login Window**.

Hope this helps, if it doesn't, it is most probably that your drive is encrypted. Check *System Preferences > Security & Privacy > FileVault*.

Comment: Thanks @emotality! It works well. Not as comfortable as a key shortcut. Is there a way to attach keyboard shortcut to Login Window? I'll look at the System Preferences.

Comment: My pleasure! You can try out with Automator for making your own scripts then add a keyboard shortcut to this service. But I mean, 2 clicks is kind of faster than looking at your keyboard to press 3 buttons at the same time hehe :P